# calculate returns for specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
   Date       price       top          
 ..............
1999-07-21  8.6912      9.674425    
1999-07-22  8.6978      8.692583    
1999-07-23  8.8127      10.760976   
1999-07-24  8.8779      8.871057    
 ..............
1999-07-27  8.8888      10.12344
...............
```

I want to create a new col called 'return'. If in a row ,'price' >'top' then I want to fill 'return' of this row with the return of price in this row and price in the n+5 row.

For example, In row 1999-07-22,the price is greater than top, so I wanto fill 'return' in this row with return 07-22 and 07-27, that is,(8.8888-8.6978)/8.6978 (notice the date may not be consecutive since holidays are excluded ). Only a small part of the rows meet the demand. So most of values in 'return' will be missing values.

Could you please tell me how I can do this in python?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `where`? That would tell you straight away that it cannot be called in this manner - the assignment of values coming _before_ the condition is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex` if necessary and then use [`Series.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html), [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and last [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

df['new'] = (df['price'].pct_change(5)
                        .shift(-5)
                        .where(df['price'] > df['top']))
print (df)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but what I understood he want to return the value in the row with date `1999-07-22`

Comment: @Erfan - Thank you.

Comment: Hi. The frequency 5 is the relative position but not 5 days. For example, if the date in the rows are 01-01,01-03,01-04,01-05,01-07,01-08, the pct_change should calculate the price between 01-01 and 01-08 rather than 01-06(which will return missing value). Could you please me help me abt this?

Comment: @JAKE - Do you think `df['price'].shift(-5).pct_change().where(df['price'] > df['top'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael haha I found that pct_change(5)
                        .shift(-5)) is right

Comment: @JAKE - Super, you can also accept yesterday answer, thank you.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your help. I am new to stackoverflow so forgot to accepted them.

Comment: @JAKE - Super, no problem :) Nice day!